# Update Textbox with Combobox value on ValueChange event

Tags: javascript, html

My ultimate goal with this is to make a  dropdown that allows user input also. The best I can seem to do is an  textbox next a dropdown that makes it look like they are similar, the issue I am running into is that I need the textbox to update whenever my dropdown value is changed. I have some code I've been playing with (below), but it doesn't seem to be getting me anywhere! Any pointers on how I can get this to work, or am I messing up the syntax? (fairly new to both jscript and html)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<style type="text/css">     
    select 
    {
        width:200px;
    }
</style>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/JavaScript">

        var select = document.getElementById('theItems');
        var input = document.getElementById('stroke');
        function otherSelect()  
        {
            input.value = select.value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="">
    <input name="stroke"/>
    <select name="theItems" onchange="otherSelect()">
        <option value="item1">Item One</option>
        <option value="item2">Item Two</option>
        <option value="item3">Item Three</option>
        <option value="item3">Item Four</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>      
    </select>

    <div id="otherBox" style="visibility: hidden;">
        If other: <input name="otherField" type="text" /> 
    </div>
</form>


</body>
```

Comment: this isn't html 5, hence the doctype -//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN, might want to remove the html5 tag

Comment: Like I said, pretty new to this stuff. Tag has been removed, but no answer has really helped me reach my goal yet. Any other possible input would be appreciated!

Comment: since you're new to javascript you may want to try out jQuery, it really simplifies some complicated procedures. I'll post my answer with jQuery and with just javascript to show you how much easier it is to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your script in the `window.onload` event. The elements are not available to your script when it is being executed. Change your script to this

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
window.onload  = function(){

    var select = document.getElementById('theItems');
    var input = document.getElementById('stroke');
    function otherSelect()  
    {
        input.value = select.value;
    }
}
</script>
```

This way the script will be executed after the HTML elements have been rendered by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple **pure JavaScript** implementation of what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/24Xhn/

We're going to setup the markup so the select box and the other input box have similar name and id attributes. We'll use classes to setup/initialize the onchange events and make sure the inputs start off hidden and disabled. By toggling the "disabled" attribute, true or false we are making it so the input or select don't show up when the form is submitted, submit the form in the JSFiddle with different combinations and you'll see the output in the query string of the URL.

HTML

```
<select id="items1" name="items1" class="select-other">
    <option value="item1">Item One</option>
    <option value="item2">Item Two</option>
    <option value="item3">Item Three</option>
    <option value="item3">Item Four</option>
    <option value="other">Other</option>      
</select>
<input id="items1-other" name="items1-other" class="input-other" />
```

JS

```
// setup
var inps = document.getElementsByClassName("input-other");
for(var i=0; i<inps.length; i++) {
    var inp = inps[i];
    // hide & disable the "other" input
    inp.style.display = "none";
    inp.disabled = true;
    // set onchange, if input is empty go back to select
    inp.onchange = function() {
        var val = this.value;
        if(val == "") {
            this.style.display = "none";
            this.disabled = true;
            // get its associated select box
            var sel = document.getElementById(this.id.replace(/-other$/i, ""));
            sel.style.display = "";
            sel.disabled = false;
        }
    };
}
var sels = document.getElementsByClassName("select-other");
for(var i=0; i<sels.length; i++) {
    var sel = sels[i];
    // set onchange if value is other switch to input
    sel.onchange = function() {
        var val = this.value;
        if(val == "other") {
            this.style.display = "none";
            this.disabled = true;
            // get associated input box
            var inp = document.getElementById(this.id + "-other");
            inp.style.display = "";
            inp.disabled = false;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized what was wrong. I didn't truly look at the html until I copied and pasted it into a test application and I figured out the issue.

You need to set the `id` tag to the `stroke` and `theItems` not the name tag. That's why it's not doing anything. There was, I'm guessing, a copy/paste issue as well because you didn't have a closing `html` tag, but I assumed you just missed copying that. Also, you don't really need global variables in order to retrieve the `input` and `select` you just need them inside the actual function, and you can actually pass the `select` into the function like so.

Your code corrected:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">     
        select 
        {
            width:200px;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function otherSelect(obj)  
        {           
            var input = document.getElementById('stroke');
            input.value = obj.value;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="">
    <input id="stroke" name="stroke"/>
    <select id="theItems" name="theItems" onchange="otherSelect(this)">
        <option value="item1">Item One</option>
        <option value="item2">Item Two</option>
        <option value="item3">Item Three</option>
        <option value="item3">Item Four</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>      
    </select>

    <div id="otherBox" style="visibility: hidden;">
        If other: <input name="otherField" type="text" /> 
    </div>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wanted to create a combobox with an auto-updating text field next to it for new entries, and came up with this in less than an hour, based on simple html and javascript examples from w3schools.com. It works perfectly on my IE browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function updateField(name, value)
{
   document.getElementById(name).value = value;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select name='10' onchange='updateField(this.name, this.value)'>
   <option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>
   <option value='saab'>Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select> 
<input type="text" id="10" value="volvo">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you change name -> id. I think this code will be better for you

```html
<form action="" method="">
    <input id="stroke"/>
    <select id="theItems" onchange="otherSelect()">
        <option value="item1">Item One</option>
        <option value="item2">Item Two</option>
        <option value="item3">Item Three</option>
        <option value="item4">Item Four</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>      
    </select>

    <div id="otherBox" style="visibility: hidden;">
        If other: <input name="otherField" type="text" /> 
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/JavaScript">
    var select = document.getElementById('theItems');
    var input = document.getElementById('stroke');
    function otherSelect() {
        input.value = select.value;
    }
</script>
```